# Проблема с десериализацией JSON в C#

Tags: c#, сериализация

У меня возникла проблема с десериализацией JSON, при том что сериализация работает. Вот мои методы для сериализации и десериализации объектов моего класса Worker.

```
public void SaveWorkers(List<Worker> workers)
{
    String filePath = @"D:\Data\JSON\Workers.json";
    DataContractJsonSerializer jsonFormatter = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Worker));
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    {
        foreach (Worker worker in workers)
        {
            jsonFormatter.WriteObject(fs, worker);
        }
    }
}

public Worker[] RestoreWorkers()
{
    String filePath = @"D:\Data\JSON\Workers.json";
    DataContractJsonSerializer jsonFormatter = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Worker[]));
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    {
        Worker[] workers = (Worker[])jsonFormatter.ReadObject(fs);
        return workers;
    }
}
```

Когда я произвожу сериализацию объектов и потом пытаюсь десериализовать их и вывести информацию о них в консоль, то выводится пустая строка.

```
Worker[] restoredWorkers = RestoreWorkers();
foreach (Worker worker in restoredWorkers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(worker.Name);
}
```

Я проверял файлы json, в которые я сериализую, там все объекты есть, но десериализация не происходит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Worker));` vs `DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Worker[]))`

Comment: `foreach (Worker worker in workers)` -  в чем смысл сериализовать их по одному? Вы же не думаете, что если вы просто налепите одну сущность за другой в файле, то файл вдруг станет валидным JSON массивом?

Comment: @tym32167 исправил эту ошибку, все заработало. Спасибо огромное за помощь!